How to place QWidget on a specific monitor
I am working in a python project that creates a QDialog as a child of another application window. I would like to place the dialog window inside its parent application main window.  The trouble I am having is when there are multiple monitors the dialog window always appears on the primary monitor (the one with upper left corner at 0,0).  Values for the dialog position that are outside on the bounds of the main monitor result in the dialog window being centered on the main monitor.
Python 3.11
pyside6
windows 10 Enterprise 22H2
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qw
import win32gui as win32

class DialogApp(qw.QDialog):

    global iRect
        
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DialogApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
    
        layout = qw.QGridLayout()
        layout.setColumnStretch(0,1)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test Dialog")
        self.setGeometry(iRect[0] + 100, iRect[1] + 100, 200, 20)
        self.setSizeGripEnabled(True)     

def mainWindow(): 
    parent_window_ptr = getMainWindow() # This function is provided by the parent application
    return wrapInstance(int(parent_window_ptr), qw.QMainWindow)

iRect = win32.GetWindowRect(parent_window_handle) # This handle is aquired using windows APIs

da = DialogApp(mainWindow()) 
da.show()

The above code will display a QDialog 100 pixels from the upper left corner of the application window only if the application window is on the main monitor.  Otherwise the QDialog will appear centered on the main monitor.
All the documentation and example I have found imply that the process I used should work.  Is there some way to force a QWidget onto a by specifying a monitor?  Using something like:
monitor_info = win32api.GetMonitorInfo(win32api.MonitorFromWindow(other_window_handle, win32con.MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY))

By default, QDialog always appears centered on its parent, no matter the screen it's placed. It's unclear what you mean by "parent application" or "another application window" (a different process? or just a different window?). Please take your time to [edit] your question in order to clarify it and provide a proper [mre] (and ensure that you properly format code before submitting the update).

Have you tried QWidget::setScreen, along with its counterpart QWidget::screen?

Thank you and my apologies musicamante, My first post.  To clarify, I am trying to make my application a child of another application's (Autodesk VRED) main window. And I want it to show up at a specific position on that window.  When the parent application's window is not on the primary monitor  I am currently unable to do this.  When the parent is not a QObject it does not appear centered on it. As Atmo suggested, I could use the setScreen method, but I do not understand how to get the screen object of a non-qt application.
